# get Item/slice in chainer.Variable doesn't support multi-GPU chainer.training.ParallelUpdater?

Tags: chainer

I have 2-dimension array , When I use following code to compute loss:

```
_roi_score = roi_score[row_index, col_index]
gt_roi_label_lst = gt_roi_label_lst[row_index, col_index]
loss = F.sigmoid_cross_entropy(roi_score, gt_roi_label_lst)  # multi label
```

during back propagation, code report error:

```
File "AU_rcnn/train.py", line 249, in main
   trainer.run()
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 324, in run
   six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
   raise value
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 310, in run
   update()
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/training/updater.py", line 223, in update
   self.update_core()
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/training/updater.py", line 367, in update_core
   loss.backward()
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/variable.py", line 916, in backward
   target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/function_node.py", line 486, in backward_accumulate
   gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/function.py", line 124, in backward
   gxs = self._function.backward(in_data, grad_out_data)
 File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer-3.0.0b1-py3.6.egg/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py", line 56, in backward
   gb = gy.sum(0)
 File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 967, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.sum
 File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 975, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.sum
 File "cupy/core/reduction.pxi", line 216, in cupy.core.core.simple_reduction_function.__call__
 File "cupy/core/elementwise.pxi", line 102, in cupy.core.core._preprocess_args
ValueError: Array device must be same as the current device: array device = 1 while current = 0
```

Although I only use one GPU, it appeared. What is reason caused this, I have stucked for long time.

Comment: Did you call the code below? if not, try inserting it at the top of the code.
`if gpu >= 0: chainer.cuda.get_device(gpu).use()  # Make a specified GPU current`. `gpu = 0` if you use the first core of gpu.

Comment: I will try it , another question: If I use roi_score[row_index, col_index] to slice chainer.Variable, because roi_score is produced by Linear link(FC), How it will back propagation? How could fc update its weight matrix only part of its produced vector involved in loss computation?

Comment: it works! thanks a lot